# Automapper. Маппинг через промежуточную сущность

Tags: c#, automapper

Скажите, как настроить маппинг между сущностями, когда у меня есть профили через промежуточную сущность?

Есть классы А Б В. Я настроил профили А-Б и Б-В. Далее я хочу указать, что маппинг А-В должен происходить через сущность Б, но при этом я не хочу каждый раз делать двойной маппинг (_mapper.Map<В>(_mapper.Map<Б>(а)) и я не хочу настраивать профиль А-В вручную (CreateMap().ForMember....).

Comment: _не хочу каждый раз делать двойной маппинг_ А как по вашему будет работать маппинг через промежуточную сущность?

Comment: @yolosora, так же и будет, только это уже буду делать не я. Я хочу просто настроить это поведение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим есть 3 класса

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name1{get;set;}
}


public class Boo
{
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}


public class Bar
{
    public string Name3 { get; set; }
}
```

Конфиг

```
Mapper.Initialize(config => {
    config.CreateMap<Foo, Boo>().ForMember(x=>x.Name2, opt=>opt.MapFrom(z=>z.Name1));
    config.CreateMap<Boo, Bar>().ForMember(x=>x.Name3, opt=>opt.MapFrom(z=>z.Name2));
    config.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
                    .ConstructUsing(f=> Mapper.Map<Boo, Bar>(Mapper.Map<Foo, Boo>(f)));     
});
```

Проверка

```
var foo = new Foo() {Name1 = "1234"};
var bar = Mapper.Map<Bar>(foo);
Console.WriteLine(bar.Name3);
```

Вывод

```
1234
```

**UPD**

Для нестатичного маппера. Конфиг

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Boo>().ForMember(x => x.Name2, opt => opt.MapFrom(z => z.Name1));
    cfg.CreateMap<Boo, Bar>().ForMember(x => x.Name3, opt => opt.MapFrom(z => z.Name2));
    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
                    .ConvertUsing((f, b, c) => c.Mapper.Map<Bar>(c.Mapper.Map<Boo>(f)));
});
config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Проверка

```
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var foo = new Foo() { Name1 = "1234" };
var bar = mapper.Map<Bar>(foo);
Console.WriteLine(bar.Name3);
```

Вывод

```
1234
```

Comment: я не использую статичный Mapper. Поэтому в нем не будет конфигов для такого преобразования. Я даже привел пример кода, чтобы это было видно. Я использую классы, наследующие профили. В этом случае у меня нет возможности заинжектить в профиль инстанс маппера, потому что на момент чтения профилей инстанса еще нет.

Comment: @iRumba думаю, имеет смысл явно писать в вопросе, что вам нужно сделать, так как мне было не ясно, что вам статичный не подходит. Но, в любом случае, обновил ответ.